# SUBTOTAL 101 formula that ignores #DIV/O

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a huge academic attendance database, of students that are filtered into subgroups, in Excel. On the first page of the workbook I have a table that details their individual absences for each class, and  their overall % of absence in the end column.

Eg in `M6` (the last cell of the first row of filtered data) I have used the formula `=AVERAGEIF(E6:K6,"<>#DIV/0!")` to work out an average for only the lessons for which I have data. The cells with the subject data in are direct look ups of `COUNTIF` results from other worksheets, which obviously return #DIV/0 messages if there is no data present.

What I need to do is get a `SUBTOTAL 101` function, or something similar, that ignores hidden cells in my filtered by "Group" ("Group being teaching group, in this instance) list  that will ignore the `#DIV/0` message, so that I can take an average by "Group" of absence and be displayed at the bottom of the table.

Please help me write a formula that essentially nests the `AVERAGEIF` formula in the `SUBTOTAL 101` formula (or vice versa, if that should be so, if it is even possible)  to give me the desired result. I would go for a VBA fix but as you can tell, I'd need it to be broken down into baby steps as my coding skills are not up to much.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Which version of Excel are you using? In Excel 2010 or later versions `AGGREGATE` function works a little bit like `SUBTOTAL` but there's an option to ignore errors too, so this formula, for example.......

`=AGGREGATE(1,7,A2:A100)`

....averages (1) the data in `A2:A100` while ignoring errors and hidden rows (7)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you avoid the problem by remove any divide-by-zeros from your worksheets.

For example if:

```
=AVERAGE(Z1:Z100)
```

is giving an error, use:

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGE(Z1:Z100),"")
```

instead